# Error installing backlogs plugin in Redmine

Tags: redmine, backlog

I have the following problem. I am trying to install the "redmine_backlogs" version 1.0.6 plugin in an environment with Redmine 3.2.0 with a Ruby 2.0.0 version

The problem gives me when I download the plugin, I host it in the plugin directory of my redmine installation, and when following the documentation, I issue the command bundle exec rake db: migrate gives me the following error:

```
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`:
[!] There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: You cannot specify the same gem twice with different version requirements.
You specified: capybara (> = 0) and capybara (~> 1.1.0). Bundler cannot continue.

 # from / var / www / redmine / plugins / redmine_backlogs / Gemfile: 51
 # -------------------------------------------
 # unless chiliproject
 > gem "capybara", "~> 1.1.0"
 # gem "poltergeist", "~> 0.6.0"
 # -------------------------------------------
. Bundler cannot continue.

 # from / var / www / redmine / Gemfile: 110
 # -------------------------------------------
 # Dir.glob File.expand_path ("../ plugins / * / {Gemfile, PluginGemfile}", __FILE__) do | file |
 > eval_gemfile file
 # end
 # -------------------------------------------
```

I can't find a way to solve it so that it is properly installed.

Any extra help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: General advice: the backlogs plugin is not under active development anymore and according to https://backlogs.github.io/www/ does not support Redmine 3.x _at all_. You might want to look around for an alternative (i.e., the Redmine Agile plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin has a `Gemfile` in it's root directory, which has an entry for the `capybara` gem.

Bundler now complains because either Redmine, or another Plugin, have an entry for the same library in their Gemfile, but with a conflicting version requirement.

As Capybara is only used for running tests, it should be safe to just remove that line from the backlog plugin's `Gemfile`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Finally I have to delete some gems that give me the same error.

Comment: Done! Now the error is different: rake aborted!
ArgumentError: The scope body needs to be callable.when I execute rake redmine:plugins:migrate

Comment: That is most likely because the backlogs plugin is not fit for use with the Rails version Redmine 3 is using. Like I said in my previous comment - don't use it, it is unmaintained.